# Read status of digital pin 11, when it is set as OUTPUT

Tags: pins

I have set `pin 11` as output.
`pinMode(11, OUTPUT);`

However, I want to be able to read its state (if it is `HIGH` or `LOW`),  however since it is set as `OUTPUT`, I am not able to use `digitalRead()`.

I found this online though:

```
Serial.println(bitRead(PORTD,3));    
//Reads bit 3 of register PORTD which contains the current state (high/low) of pin 3
```

If I want to read the state of `pin 11` then this:
`Serial.println(bitRead(PORTD,11));` will be enough? Or do I have to change the `PORT` as well?

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: please don't ask `what will happen if I do this?` ... do it first, then ask, if you do not understand something

Answer (score 2):

> however since it is set as OUTPUT, I am not able to use digitalRead().

Where did you hear that? `digitalRead()` will return the state of a pin set to OUTPUT mode. (In that case, it will be the state you last set it to). As a demonstration, this is a common idiom for inverting the state of an output pin:

```
digitalWrite(LEDPIN, !digitalRead(LEDPIN));
```